# Trigger multiple methods on event and pass event variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Using vue, I am trying to trigger multiple events on a click and pass 'event' variable, so that I can use `event.target`.

I tried this:

```
<element @click="onSubmit(), onChange()"></element>
```

And in my methods, I tried

```
methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
       console.log(e)
    },

    onChange(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
}
```

> Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template

```
<element @click="onClick"></element>
```

And in methods

```
methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
       console.log(e)
    },

    onChange(e) {
      console.log(e)
    },

    onClick(e){
      this.onSubmit(e)
      this.onChange(e)
    }
}
```

When no argument is provided, `event` is always the first argument to an event handler. Alternatively, in the template you can use `$event` to reference the current event.

```
<element @click="onClick($event)"></element>
```

I guess it should also be noted that `event` is a global variable and would be accessible in both of the functions being called without having to be passed.

```
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
       console.log(event.target) // will log the element that was clicked
    },

    onChange() {
      console.log(event.target) // will log the element that was clicked
    },

    onClick(){
      this.onSubmit()
      this.onChange()
    }
}
```